# PowerDNS pgSQL Configure Different Schema

Tags: postgresql, powerdns

I've been using PowerDNS for a few years now and finally decided to switch over to pgSQL instead of mySQL. I've been researching this question but I haven't found anything solid so I'm assuming it's probably not possible.

I'm curious if it's possible to install and run PowerDNS from within a schema called `pdns` instead of a database called `pdns`? I'm unable to find any option to tell PowerDNS to look in X database and Y schema.

For example I have a database called `example` and in this database I have two schema's called `mydb` and `pdns`. I'd like to install the PowerDNS table structure in the `pdns` schema and then run the PowerDNS service from that schema. It seems to work just fine when the tables are in the `public` schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most easily accomplished by changing the role's search path.

Create a new schema pdns within the target database. Create all the tables you need within that schema. When you create the pdns role (user), set their search path to search your pdns schema before public. Grant access on the pdns schema to the pdns role.

```
create schema pdns;
# create your tables as pdns.tablename
create role pdns with password 'yourpassword';
alter role pdns set search_path = "$user",pdns,public;
grant usage on schema pdns to pdns;
grant select,insert,update,delete on all tables in schema pdns to pdns;
grant select,update on all sequences in schema pdns to pdns;
```

If you revoke any access pdns might have to other tables, you shouldn't need to be too worried about separation. That should about do it.

*Edit:* A note; if you're new to postgres, you might not know that while you can grant access to all tables in a schema, if you add or re-add a table you must grant access to the new table (by re-running the grant command). That is why the grants in this answer are last.

Comment: Thank you, this actually does exactly what I was looking for. I really didn't want to have to hack away at the source to make this work. DNS Queries are now being resolved and I'm quite pleased with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://mailman.powerdns.com/pipermail/pdns-users/2005-July/002524.html

Much like is mentioned on this site, it might be possible via some "hacking"

```
you can fake this by redefining all gmysql queries. Extract
the current queries like this:

$ /usr/sbin/pdns_server --launch=gmysql --config 2>&1 | grep -i gmysql | grep query=

And change all instances of 'records' by 'blah-records', and insert this in
your configuration.
```

You will replace 'blah-records' with pdns.records

If that doesn't work then your only option is to write a wrapper to rewrite the postgres queries on the fly. (Probably more work than it is worth). What your asking for is unsupported, and the short answer is: **It shouldn't be done**

ps: you are on your own to find the postgres equivalents of the above command..(If they exist)